# How to extract nested JSON Elements in Liferay

Tags: java, json, liferay, liferay-6

I'm using Liferay 6.2 and have a JSONObject containing the following:

```
{
  "foo":{
         "bar":{
                "baz":["42","23"]
               }
        }
}
```

I have a String containing a path/selector/whatsitcalled pointing somewhere in that JSONObject: `foo.bar.baz[0]`

How would I go about getting the corresponding value from the JSONObject, i.e. "42"?

All methods I could find only deal with the next level down, nothing seems to cover nesting. I could parse the path manually, but isn't there an easier way?

Comment: I know, that `eval` is evil. Nevertheless, what about: `eval('myObjectName.' + selector)` with `selector = 'foo.bar.baz[0]';`?

Comment: I'm working with Java, not Javascript, so `eval` is not an option. (And using a ScriptEngine to execute JS just feels like a bad idea...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this java library to perform xpath similar query for json.
I've used it with success in Liferay.

https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

Comment: This looks like a promising solution. I'd have to convert the JSON to a String instead of working on the JSONObject itself, but it should work, thank you!

Comment: Instead of converting to string, JsonPath libray has several adapters to vary json framework. `org.json` is supported, work on it and only at last point, converto to liferay json.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to retrive data programatically from JSON object.

You can use the own Liferay support JSON library, GSON or Jackson libraries ( I recommend you the last one, it is really powerful).